# AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'hit_paddle'

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

def hit_paddle(self, pos):
    paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
    if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
        if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
            return True
        return False

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False

    def draw(self):

        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 2




tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Whenever I run this code it gives an attribute error that says ball object has no attribute hit_paddle can someone please help me? I have been learning this from a book but the picture on the book has no errors while when I run it, it is giving me an error  can someone please help me with this please. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because `hit_paddle` is defined *outside* the class `Ball`…‽

Answer (score 1):

`hit_paddle` isn't defined within `Ball`, it has to be indented and beneath `Ball` to be considered in scope. For instance, this is correct:

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        ...

    def draw(self):
        ...
    
    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        ...
```

While this (similar to what you have) is incorrect, because `hit_paddle` is not defined within `Ball`:

```
def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        ...

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        ...

    def draw(self):
        ...
```

This is a very basic misunderstanding of how functions and classes work, if you're making these kinds of mistakes I recommend taking some basic beginner Python tutorials.